# Is it possible to have statements inside a ternary operator (in generated code)?

Tags: c, expression, ternary-operator

Disclaimer: I'm not writing code like this, I know it's ugly and unreadable.

I'm generating C, and I need everything to be in one expression.

This works:

```
#define true 1
int a  = (true) ? ( (true) ? (puts("a"), puts("b"),  1) : (2) ) : (3);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

```
a
b
1
```

But I also need to have statements, not just expressions. This fails to compile:

```
int a  = (true) ? ( (true) ? (puts("a"), puts("b"), (if (true) puts("c");),  1) : (2) ) : (3);
```

```
error: expected expression
```

Is it impossible to achieve in C?

Comment: Posting your actual code would be a better idea, perhaps there is [no need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to use gnu extensions at all.

Comment: You can use a ternary expression instead of an if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), you can wrap around the statements in braces, like

```
int a  = (true) ? ( (true) ? (puts("a"), puts("b"), ({if (true) puts("c");}),  1) : (2) ) : (3);
```

Comment: It's really amazing how flexible C is. Perfect for code generation.

Comment: This is a GCC extension

Comment: Clang supports some gcc extensions

Comment: @Alex And I was right after all ;p Compile with `-pedantic -Werror` ...

Comment: Just wondering, who removed almost half of comments here? Why?

Comment: @Alex Maybe they got flagged and removed. Comments are not supposed to live long, anyways.

Comment: @SouravGhosh but they were just usual comments. For example your comment about while statements as expressions.

Comment: @Alex Not sure, sometimes people flag relevant comments, too. You never know.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have statements inside an expression, no. However, as you noted, you can have boolean operators and the ternary operator.

```
if (true) puts("c");
```

can be written in an expression like

```
true ? puts("c") : false
```

or

```
true && puts("c")
```

Comment: Thanks. Can loops be written as expressions somehow?

Comment: @Alex Nitpick: `if` is a condition, not a loop.